# how to pushup the content when clicks on dropdown list item in bootstarp

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

> > Hi,My question is how to drag the content when clicks on any option in
> >     dropdown,colud you please tel me...
> >         it is leftside menu-bar,when clicks on any dropdown item it is covering the below menu-bar list,so i need to drag the other menu bar
> >     list when clicks on any dropdown list..

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
                            </a>

                        </li>
                        <li class="active dropdown">

                            <a href="general.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="fa fa-gavel"></i> <span>General <span class="caret"></span></span>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="#General1" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="tab" >General1</a></li>
                                        <li><a  href="#General2" class="btn btn-success"  data-toggle="tab" >General2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#General3" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="tab">General3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="basic_form.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i> <span>Basic Elements</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="simple.html">
                                <i class="fa fa-glass"></i> <span>Simple tables</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
```

Comment: Please stop using `blockquote` for anything other than actual `quotes`. Regarding the question, it is **unclear what you are asking**. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying your question.

Comment: actually my question is,when clicks on dropdown list i.e General it shouldn't cover the below  elements that are Basic Elements,Simple tables(refer the above code)@Andrei Gheorghiu